# Scraping from an External table

Tags: php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I've an external vendor, who is providing me an Iframe data, his iframe is not responsive and my site is responsive, so there is a mismatch while showing the iframe in my site.

So i was looking at simple html dom parser to fetch the content from the remote url and then displaying the content in a boostrapped table.

the table in iframe looks like below:

```html
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_InnerTable"><table CellSpacing=0 cellpadding=0 Width=100% ><tr class='GridHeaderclass'><td class=GridHeadLeft>Particulars  </td><td class=GridHeadCenter>Dec&nbsp;2014</td><td class=GridHeadCenter>Dec&nbsp;2013</td><td class=GridHeadCenter>Dec&nbsp;2012</td><td class=GridHeadCenter>Dec&nbsp;2011</td><td class=GridHeadCenter>Dec&nbsp;2010</td></tr><tr class='GridRow_Default'id="R3" ><td class=GridDataLeft>Operational & Financial Ratios</td><td class=GridDataRight>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight_Alt>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight_Alt>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr></tr><tr class='GridAltRow_Default'id="R5" ><td class=GridDataLeft>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;CEPS(Rs)</td><td class=GridDataRight>16.11&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight_Alt>13.22&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight>10.92&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight_Alt>12.46&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight>5.42&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr></tr><tr class='GridAltRow_Default'id="R7" ><td class=GridDataLeft>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Book NAV/Share(Rs)</td><td class=GridDataRight>132.70&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight_Alt>126.36&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight>122.61&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight_Alt>119.61&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight>114.38&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr></tr><tr class='GridRow_Default'id="R9" ><td class=GridDataLeft>Margin Ratios</td><td class=GridDataRight>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight_Alt>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight_Alt>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr></tr><tr class='GridAltRow_Default'id="R11" ><td class=GridDataLeft>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;EBIT Margin(%)</td><td class=GridDataRight>5.85&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight_Alt>4.74&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight>3.28&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight_Alt>4.22&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight>2.05&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr></tr><tr class='GridAltRow_Default'id="R13" ><td class=GridDataLeft>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;PAT Margin (%)</td><td class=GridDataRight>2.80&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight_Alt>2.16&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight>1.71&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight_Alt>2.48&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight>0.96&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr></tr><tr class='GridRow_Default'id="R15" ><td class=GridDataLeft>Performance Ratios</td><td class=GridDataRight>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight_Alt>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight_Alt>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr></tr><tr class='GridAltRow_Default'id="R17" ><td class=GridDataLeft>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ROE(%)</td><td class=GridDataRight>8.33&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight_Alt>6.71&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight>5.35&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight_Alt>7.44&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight>2.62&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr></tr><tr class='GridAltRow_Default'id="R19" ><td class=GridDataLeft>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Asset Turnover(x)</td><td class=GridDataRight>0.78&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight_Alt>0.88&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight>1.12&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight_Alt>1.24&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight>1.17&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr></tr><tr class='GridAltRow_Default'id="R21" ><td class=GridDataLeft>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Working Capital/Sales(x)</td><td class=GridDataRight>8.31&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight_Alt>9.56&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight>8.21&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight_Alt>7.06&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight>4.19&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr></tr><tr class='GridAltRow_Default'id="R23" ><td class=GridDataLeft>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Fixed Capital/Sales(x)</td><td class=GridDataRight>0.24&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight_Alt>0.21&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight>0.19&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight_Alt>0.17&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight>0.14&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr></tr><tr class='GridAltRow_Default'id="R25" ><td class=GridDataLeft>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Inventory Days</td><td class=GridDataRight>42.12&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight_Alt>42.51&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight>41.97&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight_Alt>39.77&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight>39.41&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr></tr><tr class='GridRow_Default'id="R27" ><td class=GridDataLeft>Valuation Parameters</td><td class=GridDataRight>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight_Alt>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight_Alt>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr></tr><tr class='GridAltRow_Default'id="R29" ><td class=GridDataLeft>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;PCE(x)</td><td class=GridDataRight>79.85&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight_Alt>52.39&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight>64.11&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight_Alt>46.83&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight>146.12&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr></tr><tr class='GridAltRow_Default'id="R31" ><td class=GridDataLeft>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Yield(%)</td><td class=GridDataRight>0.29&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight_Alt>0.43&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight>0.43&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight_Alt>0.51&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight>0.25&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr></tr><tr class='GridAltRow_Default'id="R33" ><td class=GridDataLeft>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;EV/Core EBITDA(x)</td><td class=GridDataRight>46.44&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight_Alt>30.47&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight>42.25&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight_Alt>30.76&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight>86.70&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr></tr><tr class='GridAltRow_Default'id="R35" ><td class=GridDataLeft>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;EV/CE(x)</td><td class=GridDataRight>2.64&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight_Alt>1.42&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight>1.86&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight_Alt>1.93&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight>2.81&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr></tr><tr class='GridRow_Default'id="R37" ><td class=GridDataLeft>Growth Ratio</td><td class=GridDataRight>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight_Alt>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight_Alt>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr></tr><tr class='GridAltRow_Default'id="R39" ><td class=GridDataLeft>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Core EBITDA Growth(%)</td><td class=GridDataRight>19.97&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight_Alt>37.67&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight>-9.25&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight_Alt>110.66&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight>-69.87&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr></tr><tr class='GridAltRow_Default'id="R41" ><td class=GridDataLeft>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;PAT Growth(%)</td><td class=GridDataRight>29.18&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight_Alt>28.73&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight>-25.54&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight_Alt>191.85&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight>-82.17&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr></tr><tr class='GridRow_Default'id="R43" ><td class=GridDataLeft>Financial Stability Ratios</td><td class=GridDataRight>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight_Alt>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight_Alt>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr></tr><tr class='GridAltRow_Default'id="R45" ><td class=GridDataLeft>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Current Ratio(x)</td><td class=GridDataRight>1.17&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight_Alt>1.14&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight>1.25&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight_Alt>1.28&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight>1.47&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr></tr><tr class='GridAltRow_Default'id="R47" ><td class=GridDataLeft>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Interest Cover(x)</td><td class=GridDataRight>3.91&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight_Alt>3.35&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight>4.62&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight_Alt>6.77&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class=GridDataRight>3.86&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr></tr></table></td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Now can anyone please guide me on using the simple html dom parser so that i can display values from the above table in my own boostrap table.

The code which i tried, is returning values, but they are repeating again and again and are not formatting themselves into tables.

```html
<?php
require('simple_html_dom.php');

$table = array();

$html = file_get_html('www.iframeprovidorURL.com');
foreach($html->find('table') as $e){
    foreach($e->find('td') as $f){
        echo strip_tags($f->innertext) . '<br>';
    }
}

?>
```

I've also tried:

```html
<?php

$html_string = file_get_contents('http://iframeURL.com');
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html_string);
libxml_clear_errors();
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$values = array();
$row = $xpath->query('//td[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_InnerTable"]');
foreach($row as $value) {
    $values[] = trim($value->textContent);
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($values);
?>
```

The above results in:

```html
Array
(
    [0] => Particulars  DecÂ 2014DecÂ 2013DecÂ 2012DecÂ 2011DecÂ 2010Operational & Financial RatiosÂ Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â CEPS(Rs)16.11Â Â 13.22Â Â 10.92Â Â 12.46Â Â 5.42Â Â Â Â Â Book NAV/Share(Rs)132.70Â Â 126.36Â Â 122.61Â Â 119.61Â Â 114.38Â Â Margin RatiosÂ Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â EBIT Margin(%)5.85Â Â 4.74Â Â 3.28Â Â 4.22Â Â 2.05Â Â Â Â Â PAT Margin (%)2.80Â Â 2.16Â Â 1.71Â Â 2.48Â Â 0.96Â Â Performance RatiosÂ Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â ROE(%)8.33Â Â 6.71Â Â 5.35Â Â 7.44Â Â 2.62Â Â Â Â Â Asset Turnover(x)0.78Â Â 0.88Â Â 1.12Â Â 1.24Â Â 1.17Â Â Â Â Â Working Capital/Sales(x)8.31Â Â 9.56Â Â 8.21Â Â 7.06Â Â 4.19Â Â Â Â Â Fixed Capital/Sales(x)0.24Â Â 0.21Â Â 0.19Â Â 0.17Â Â 0.14Â Â Â Â Â Inventory Days42.12Â Â 42.51Â Â 41.97Â Â 39.77Â Â 39.41Â Â Valuation ParametersÂ Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â PCE(x)79.85Â Â 52.39Â Â 64.11Â Â 46.83Â Â 146.12Â Â Â Â Â Yield(%)0.29Â Â 0.43Â Â 0.43Â Â 0.51Â Â 0.25Â Â Â Â Â EV/Core EBITDA(x)46.44Â Â 30.47Â Â 42.25Â Â 30.76Â Â 86.70Â Â Â Â Â EV/CE(x)2.64Â Â 1.42Â Â 1.86Â Â 1.93Â Â 2.81Â Â Growth RatioÂ Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Core EBITDA Growth(%)19.97Â Â 37.67Â Â -9.25Â Â 110.66Â Â -69.87Â Â Â Â Â PAT Growth(%)29.18Â Â 28.73Â Â -25.54Â Â 191.85Â Â -82.17Â Â Financial Stability RatiosÂ Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Current Ratio(x)1.17Â Â 1.14Â Â 1.25Â Â 1.28Â Â 1.47Â Â Â Â Â Interest Cover(x)3.91Â Â 3.35Â Â 4.62Â Â 6.77Â Â 3.86Â Â 
)
```

The above is much better than the earlier one, but how does this output be tidied up in a boostrap table? and i dont know where is Â Â Â in the output coming from.

Also wanted to know would DOM parsing be faster than showing iframe? because currently the iframe pages of my site are awfully slow.

regards

Comment: Regarding speed: in an iframe a page is loaded over the internet connection of the user, so speed depends on that. Parsing is probably done on your server. You still have to load the same page the iframe is loading, so the size and the upload speed of the source is the same, but download speed now depends on your server's connection.

Comment: Okay, so effectively parsing would be a tad faster? or it would be slower because there is one more stop? Iframe host->Server->User

Comment: It really depends. If for example all your users are in China and the iframe host is in America but your parser host is also in China downloading would be faster :)

Comment: Okay Got It, but now to the main issue, how do i parse the iframe into my own table?